# pinescript Modulo/Modulus Operator v5 not working

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, modulo

I am trying to find the difference between a candle high and low and then see if it is divisible by 3
I got a 63-pip candle but the modulo operator is not working for this candle.

```
d = (high[1] - low[1])/GetPipSize() 
v = d % 3
a := label.new(x=bar_index[1],y=open[1], text = str.tostring(d) + " - " + str.tostring(v))
array.push(lblArr,a)
if array.size(lblArr) > 1 
    label.delete(array.shift(lblArr))
```

Please see the image for the candle and label getting printed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWbnN.png)

Although the candle is 63 it shows a reminder as 3 with the modulo operator.

Can you suggest where I am going wrong?

I am expecting a reminder result of zero

Comment: Please share a compilable code. What are ticker id, exchange name, timeframe and date/time of that specific candle?